# GtkStyleProvider - providing own implementation

Tags: css, c, gtk, styling, vala

I am trying to provide my own implementation of a `GtkStyleProvider`, since the "normal" CSS provider is a lot of work and extra processing to use in my case.

I want to be able to provide widget styling based on some internal state, and to do this in CSS, I'd have to write out a huge string of CSS (translating things like `Pango.FontDescription`s into CSS-style declarations) based on any change in state, and then feed it into a `GktCssProvider` which will process it *back* into Gtk-land. Compare to a custom provider, which will just signal (somehow) that its client widgets should ask it for style and it hand out new styling based directly on the state.

It seems that `GtkStyleProvider` is a way to achieve that - I can make a provider that returns styling based on some state, and add it as a style provider to the relevant `GtkStyleContext`. The (C) interface is

```
// deprecated - return NULL in new code
GtkIconFactory *      gtk_style_provider_get_icon_factory (
                                   GtkStyleProvider *provider,
                                   GtkWidgetPath *path);)  
// deprecated - return NULL in new code
GtkStyleProperties *  gtk_style_provider_get_style (
                                   GtkStyleProvider *provider,
                                   GtkWidgetPath *path))
// return true if property found and has a value, else false
gboolean              gtk_style_provider_get_style_property (
                                   GtkStyleProvider *provider,
                                   GtkWidgetPath *path,
                                   GtkStateFlags state,
                                   GParamSpec *pspec,
                                   GValue *value);
```

To this end, I wrote something like this, which I expected to work, but do nothing, as it should always report the property is not set:

```
# compile with: valac styleprov.vala --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg gdk-3.0
using Gtk;
using Gdk;

public class DerivedStyleProvider : Object, Gtk.StyleProvider
{
    public unowned Gtk.IconFactory get_icon_factory (Gtk.WidgetPath path)
    {
        return (Gtk.IconFactory) null; // Evil cast to work around buggy declaration in VAPI file
    }

    public Gtk.StyleProperties get_style (Gtk.WidgetPath path)
    {
        return (Gtk.StyleProperties) null; // Evil cast to work around buggy declaration in VAPI file
    }

    public bool get_style_property (Gtk.WidgetPath path,
                Gtk.StateFlags state,
                GLib.ParamSpec pspec,
                out GLib.Value value)
    {
        stdout.printf("get_style_property");
        // Compiler happiness for testing
        value = Value (typeof (string));
        return false; //TODO
    }
}

public class styleprov.MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    construct {
        DerivedStyleProvider styleProvider = new DerivedStyleProvider();

        // but this would work
        //Gtk.CssProvider styleProvider = new Gtk.CssProvider();
        //styleProvider.load_from_data("*{ background-color: #ff0000; }");

        StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(this.get_screen(),
                                             styleProvider,
                                             Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    }
}

class styleprov.Main : GLib.Object
{
        public void run() {
            styleprov.MainWindow mainWindow = new styleprov.MainWindow();
            mainWindow.show_all();
        }

        public static int main (string[] args) {
            Gtk.init (ref args);

            Main app = new Main();
            app.run();
            Gtk.main ();
            return 0;
        }
}
```

This compiles OK, and runs up, but almost spews warnings:

```
(styleprov:32365): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:2523: signal '-gtk-private-changed' is invalid for instance '0x1154ac0' of type 'DerivedStyleProvider'
(styleprov:32365): Gtk-WARNING **: (gtkstylecascade.c:256):gtk_style_cascade_lookup: code should not be reached
(styleprov:32365): Gtk-WARNING **: (gtkstylecascade.c:256):gtk_style_cascade_lookup: code should not be reached
...several of these....
```

Warnings notwithstanding, the `get_style_property()` method never appears to be called, and so no custom styling can be provided.

Replacing the `DerivedStyleProvider` with a "normal" CSS provider works fine.

What is the right way to implement a custom `GtkStyleProvider` (in any language)?

Comment: I had a quick look at GtkCssProvider and it implements *two* interfaces, `GtkStyleProvider` and `GtkStyleProviderPrivate`. It's possible that you have to provide an implementation for the second interface as well. I'm no Gtk+ expert though ...

Comment: The declaration (C code) is here: https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkstyleproviderprivate.h

Comment: BTW: Why do you have to heavily customize your ui style anyway? I kind of smell an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. You might want to take a step back and rethink your design. Drawing the UI yourself with Clutter, Cairo or something similary might be an alternative.

Comment: It actually wasn't a large amount of styling or very complex, it's just constructing CSS as strings seemed roundabout to me, and I was distracted by the API promises of `GtkStyleProvider`, which turns out to not usable in the way I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of `GtkCssProvider`, which appears to use not only `GtkStyleProviderInterface` but also `GtkStyleProviderPrivateInterface`, and a lot of complex custom bypassing (apparently for efficiency reasons, according to the friendly folks on he GTK+ IRC channel), I decided to just use the normal CSS method and just deal with constructing the CSS by hand as a string.

The mechanism is:

- A `GtkCssProvider` is created
- Provider is attached to the relevant style context with `gtk_style_context_add_provider()` (or the global `gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen()`)
- Data manager sends a signal that the data has changed
- This is caught by my Data->CSS translator which generates a new CSS string for the relevant `GtkCssProvider`
- This string is fed in to the existing provider with `gtk_css_provider_load_from_data()`.
- Any UI changes resulting from that update will happen automatically

I suppose the problem is likely that I don't fully understand how GTK+ works underneath. If you treat the CSS as *the* canonical style "oracle" for the UI, then I suppose that updating the CSS really *is actually the correct approach*, and I'm expecting a low-level access that is perhaps technically possible, but is not "correct" in the GTK+ way.

This low-level access is what I have grown to expect from other frameworks where you (only) have direct control over the styling of things like "background colour" of widgets, and there's no CSS layer to abstract it, but is just not how it works in GTK+ (any more).

At least, that's how I understand it!

Comment: Yeah, this is what I arrived at, too. Like you, I did wish that I had direct access to the properties, but I understood that things were written such that the CSS is the source. The internal transformation of that into GObject stuff is not public API, probably because making promises about it would be a maintenance nightmare and stand in the way of parser rewrites/optimisations/etc. Since the style machinery needs to be able to consume CSS, it makes sense to have that as the only route in, then they only have to maintain one API surface.